# No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, memorystream

I'm trying to load image from my **.mdb** database in WPF. I'm using this code :

```
public void loadimg()
{
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from recents", con);
    DataTable table = new DataTable;
    OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    adap.Fill(table);
    if (table.Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        MsgBox("nooo");
    }
    else
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter stm;
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        int bufferSize = 100;
        byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize + 1];
        long retval;
        long startIndex = 0;
        string pubID = "";
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
        reader.Read();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            startIndex = 0;
            retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
            while (retval == bufferSize)
            {
                writer.Write(outByte);
                writer.Flush();
                startIndex += bufferSize;
                retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval - 1);
            writer.Flush();
        }

        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        System.Drawing.Image _Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        image1.Source = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
    }
}
```

The code above returns an error :

> No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.

I spent hours trying to figure out how to fix it.Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Update**
In the comments, i was asked if i inserted the data properly..Well,here's the code i used to insert the data :

```
public void adddata()
{
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into   recents(Pic)values(@pic)", con);
byte[] data;
System.Drawing.Image myimage =  System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("E:\\19686468_1419770068104721_1127495277_o.png");
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    myimage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    data = ms.ToArray();
}

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", data);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
}
```

Please help me out!

Comment: Which line gives the error? Assuming it's the last line my guess would be that you're consuming the stream twice (first on the previous line) without seeking back to the start. I don't recall, but I *think* it might not be possible when using Image.FromStream. You might have to make another copy of the data first.

Comment: the `image.fromstream` trows the error....any help ?

Comment: Have you googled for that message? I get a few hits when I try it. Add some details to your question to indicate what you've tried, and what results you got. And what you googled, and in what way those solutions failed you.

Comment: i tried to convert the memorystream to a writeable bitmap but with no luck.....

Comment: and @GreatBigBore, i googled it and tried each and every solution given in msdn,codeproject.SO and even in asp.net forums but with no luck..the problem is, none faced my scenery(error while retreiving image from db) before as google results show other scenarios

Comment: i even asked this qs on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d360feff-2b42-4cf6-8b36-aaf3b9584d2b/no-imaging-component-suitable-to-complete-the-operation-was-found?forum=vbgeneral) but with no luck

Comment: It sounds to me like the actual image data you’ve loaded from the DB isn’t valid. Are you sure that it was 1. valid image data to start with (a format supported by WPF), 2. it was converted and stored in the DB correctly 3. it has been loaded back out of the DB correctly. Just quickly looking at you code the way you load the data out of the DB into the memory stream looks very strange, and likely fraught with errors, so I’d guess #3

Comment: It looks like OleDbDataReader has a GetStream method. Why not use that and simply call CopyTo to copy it the the MemoryStream? Also it looks like you are copying multiple rows all to the same MemoryStream? Is that intentional?

Comment: @DaveM,please re-read my post

Comment: @dave,u said i'm copying multiple rows,well my db has only 1 record in it....

Answer (score -2):

Fixed it...For anyone who faces this error in future :

1. Make sure you're inserting the data in the proper way(sometimes corrupted data in the db causes such errors)

2 . You don't need to do some heavy coding to convert the image to byte!

Finally,let's code :

```
public void loadimg()
{
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from recents", con);
    OleDbDataReader _dr;
    _dr = cmd.ExecuteReader;
    byte[] _photo;
    while (_dr.Read())
    {
        try
        {
            _photo = (byte[])_dr(1);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            using (MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(_photo))
            {
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bi.StreamSource = strm;
                bi.EndInit();
            }
            image1.Source = bi;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use System.Drawing.Image in a WPF application. This code is horrible. You can *directly* decode a WPF BitmapImage or BitmapFrame from `strm`, like `bi.StreamSource = strm`.

Comment: `bi.StreamSource = strm` returns "No imagingcomponent" error

Comment: Not if the byte array contains a valid bitmap frame that WPF can decode, e.g. a BMP, PNG, JPEG etc. If you store a valid bitmap, you can also retrieve a valid bitmap from your database. The whole System.Drawing.Image stuff is nonsense here.

Comment: @Clemens, i realized what u said...so, is it that if the picture was valid,the code in my question would've worked ?

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: But, as mt answer's code is working, can u tell me why it's not appropiate ?

Comment: I already told you three times. First, because `System.Drawing.Image` is WinForms, not WPF. It shouldn't be used in a WPF appliocation. Second, because an *intermediate* bitmap is not at all necessary for decoding.

Comment: Thank u so much for this info, i never knew this as i(on the firs hand) used this code without understanding...

Comment: Then please try to remove the intermediate bitmap from the code in your answer. Right now it's just horrible. I can't understand why someone upvoted it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165813/discussion-between-f-raiyan-and-clemens).

Comment: i should rather remove my answer and then post the right ans with the right code...oke ?

Comment: Better edit the existing answer. Just remove the old code parts.

Comment: please gimme 2 mins to test the code i'll come back with the result

Comment: yeah!! It worked...thank u so much...editing the ans r8 now

Comment: Fixed your edit. Note that you should *always* close a Stream, e.g. by putting it in a *using* block.

Comment: why should i always close a astream ?

Comment: Because it stays open otherwise and resources aren't freed. That doesn't hurt much for a MemoryStream, but very much for e.g. a FileStream. So as a general rule, always close it.

Comment: ow....okey, thank u so much! :)